# Relative invariants of prehomogeneous vector space

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $(G,\rho,V)$ be a prehomogeneous vector spaces with $f_1,\dots,f_N$ the basic irreducible relative invariants. Suppose that $(G',\rho',V')$ is a second prehomogeneous that is in the same castling class of the previous one. Is there a way to compute the basic irreducible relative invariants of the second one starting from $f_1,\dots,f_N$? and if they are just castling transforms of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is discussed on pp.67-68 of Sato-Kimura, "A classification of irreducible prehomogeneous vector spaces".